# C++ Interop DLL and References, and the /FU Forced Includes directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, interop

I am modifying an Interop project and I'm confused how one single .cpp file has the /FU compiler option applied that matches any references added under the References section, although it isn't actually listed under "Forced #using File".

It is only the file named `"MyProject.Interop.cpp"` that has this /FU option listed.

I followed the assumption that maybe it was because the cpp file matches the name of the project file, however I can rename MyProject.Interop.cpp to Bob.cpp and it will still end up with the /FU option set to whatever dlls I add to References.

If you actually look inside the `.vcxproj` file there is no references to the /FU option.  If I manually add one in the advanced section under C++\Advanced then it appears in the XML under a `ForcedIncludeFiles` tag.

So with the following project setting

```
<Reference Include="MyCSharpLibrary">
    <Private>false</Private>
  <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>false</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
</Reference>
```

`/FU` would appear under the `Command Line` section of the C++ tool

I also had a look to see if it inherits any special .props file and it doesn't.

This came about because I wanted to split the implementation of classes that where all within the MyProject.Interop.cpp, so as to organise them by class, but then they don't compile because the implicit `#using` is not generated for those files

Does anyone know what it is about the project settings, that makes this one file special?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot more fiddling with the project and investigating various options, the answer is that any .cpp file that has /clr enabled on it automatically receives the `/FU` option for every reference included in the reference section of the project